# Send files to Symantec AV Scan Engine from a C# Application

Tags: .net, antivirus

We need to scan files as they are being uploaded using the Symantec AV Scan Engine from our .Net Application, which supports [ICAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Content_Adaptation_Protocol)
Any pointers on how to go about this would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SCAN Engine SDK which is bundled with the scan engine download has a decent wrapper for icap in C, Java and C#.
Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

Typically the ICAP endpoint is supported in enterprise class deployments but not the $39 stuff you purchase at Best Buy. What is your scenario of deployment?